# Namespace has not been declared

Tags: c++

I have a namespace like:

HW.h

```
#include <select.h>
namespace Hw
{
    void setInput(uint8_t type, uint8_t input, ESelect select);
    void setParam(uint8_t param, ESelect select);
}
```

select.h

```
enum class ESelect
{
    Select0, 
    Select1, 
    Select2
}
```

Both of the above are in the same static library.  I try to call this from another static library, like this.

Test.cpp

```
#include<HW.h>
#include<select.h>
Hw::setInput( 0, 2, ESelect::Select0 );
```

I get the error:

```
error: ‘Hw’ has not been declared
error: ‘ESelect’ has not been declared
```

What can be wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `#include <some_header.h>` causes the compiler to search the system include directories before any user directories. Many *nix systems have a system header called `select.h` already, so you are probably including that instead of your own `select.h`.

Change all occurrences of:

```
#include <select.h>
```

to:

```
#include "select.h"
```

Ditto for `#include <HW.h>`.

Ideally you should not use system header names for your own headers, and you should always use `""` for user headers and `<>` for system headers.

For future reference, a useful technique for debugging such problems is to use `g++ -E ...` or equivalent to see what headers are actually being included.

Comment: Thanks, this did the trick.  I was thinking as it is a different library I would need <>

Comment: Nope - only use `<>` for system headers, i.e. those in `/usr/include`, `/usr/local/include`, etc - use `""` for anything non-system, i.e. your own stuff.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you do not have

```
#include "HW.h"
```

in Test.cpp

Comment: This, or circular inclusion is involved.

Comment: sorry, I missed that.  It is there, I will edit the question.